# 3 vectors in $\mathbb R^3$ which are linearly dependent, and two of them are linearly independent

Tags: vector-spaces

Find three vectors in $\mathbb R^3$ which are linearly dependent, and are such that any two of them are linearly independent?

Answer (score 6):

Take two non colinear vectors $u$ and $v$ and the third vector any linear combination of these vectors e.g $u+v$.

Answer (score 2):

$(0,0,1),(0,1,0)$ and $(0,1,1)$.